# Select SQL event log with 5 previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to track down a specific event and I want to list also the 5 previous rows.

I can list all the events this way:

```
select *
from Payment
where PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%'
```

but as I want to list also the 5 previous rows I would like to create a query that search for the primary key:

```
select *
from Payment
where PrimaryKey between (select PrimaryKey -5
                          from TablePayment
                          where PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%')
                     and (select PrimaryKey 
                          from TablePayment
                          where PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%')
```

Of course this is not working because instead of giving 2 numbers I'm giving to SQL a list of numbers.

So how to organize a **function** or **loop** that could query the 5 previous rows of every event?

Comment: What if more than one event matches the `WHERE` condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 5 *
from Payment
WHERE PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%'
ORDER BY
   PrimaryKey DESC
```

you can use SELECT TOP and sort descending to get the 5 most recent events matching your where statement but as Gordon appropriately points out you might also get more than 1 event.  If you want 5 latest records per event that meet your criteria I would use ROW_NUMBER() function available since SQL-Server 2008.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    select *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PaymentCardNumber ORDER BY PrimaryKey DESC) as RowNumber
    from Payment
    WHERE PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%'
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNumber <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
WITH e AS (
      SELECT PrimaryKey
      FROM Payment
      WHERE PaymentCardNumber like '%MyEvent%'
     )
SELECT e.PrimaryKey as comparisonPK, p.*
FROM e OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 5 p.*
      FROM p
      WHERE p.PrimaryKey < e.PrimaryKey
      ORDER BY p.PrimaryKey DESC
     ) p
UNION ALL
SELECT e.PrimaryKey as comparisonPK, p.*
FROM e OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 5 p.*
      FROM p
      WHERE p.PrimaryKey > e.PrimaryKey
      ORDER BY p.PrimaryKey ASC
     ) p
ORDER BY comparisonPK, PrimaryKey;
```

The CTE gets the primary key of the events you care about.  The `OUTER APPLY` chooses five rows before and after that row.